# How concatenate recordset variables to use filter method - Vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to concatenate multiple variables on my recordset filter. Here more information :

- `rs` is recordset
- `titre` can be M. or Mme or S. (come from rs)
- `Nom` is of the form (come from rs) : FirstName LastName (with space between)

but I can't. I tried :

```
space = " "
rs.Filter = "[titre+ space + Nom] = '" & oLookFullName & "' and nomEntreprise = '" & objContact.CompanyName & "'"
```

```
Concatenation = rs!titre + " " + rs!Nom
rs.Filter = "Concatenation = '" & oLookFullName & "'"
```

Any ideas ?

```
                                         EDIT
```

@Gustav, I tried your code with split and it seems the filter contains the correct value but just after I have this `if` loop and in this case rs.EOF is true while the contact exists... why ?

```
If rs.EOF Then 'Or (rs.BOF = True) Then
    Debug.Print oLookFullName & " is not found."
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```vb
rs.Filter = "[titre] & ' ' & [Nom] = '" & oLookFullName & "' And [nomEntreprise] = '" & objContact.CompanyName & "'"
```

or:

```vb
rs.Filter = "[titre] = '" & Split(oLookFullName, " ")(0) & "' And [Nom] = '" & Split(oLookFullName, " ")(1) & "' And [nomEntreprise] = '" & objContact.CompanyName & "'"
```

Comment: Run-time error 3001 Arguments are of the wrong type or out of acceptable range or are in conflict with one another. at the line you proposed but oLookFullName and objcontact.CompanyName takes the correct values. `titre` and `Nom` come from `rs`

Comment: Try splitting the full name.

Comment: You'll have to debug your data. Double-check your Filter string.

Comment: I just change the parameters of the function split and it works ;)